# jPanel shows empty tooltip text

Tags: java, jpanel, tooltip

I have a few radio buttons and then a checkbox, I have tooltip's for the radio buttons but not the checkbox. Which works okay, unless I get a radio to display it's tool tip text and then quickly move to the checkbox, before the tip disappears, and now I have my mouse on the checkbox but it is displaying the tooltip for the previously moused over radio button.

I tried setting a blank (`""`) tool tip for the checkbox, which works okay except that it displayed a very small tooltip square.

Is there anyway to either force the previous tooltip to go away or to properly set a nothing tooltip for the checkbox?

```
    radioButtonsetText("text");
    radioButton.setToolTipText("tooltip text");
    checkBox.setText("text");
    checkBox.setToolTipText("");
```

Comment: Got a **[runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** which demonstrates your problem? This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

> or to properly set a nothing tooltip for the checkbox?

Components don't have a tooltip by default. So don't set the tooltip and your won't have a problem.

If you set the text and want to remove it the try using:

```
component.setToolTipText(null);
```